# what is the data type for both date and time in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopback

I have date and time in following format `2018-10-31T10:30`. I want to define a data type for this in loopback model. I have gone through internet and putting my head aroung for hours now but didn't find solution about which data type should I use for this format in loopback.

I tried with

```
type: "timestamp"
```

OR

```
type: "date"
dataType: "timestamp"
```

OR

```
type: "datetime"
```

but none works

While compiling I get below warning

> Swagger: skipping unknown type "timestamp".

So what is the correct data type for this format `2018-10-31T10:30`

Answer (score 2):

"myDate": {
      "type": "string",
      "dataType": "date",
...
}

REf: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/issues/149

Answer (score 1):

So this is how the createdOn property in my model will look like.
the data type in loopback is Date and in MySQL it is datetime. The conversion of javascript date to MySQL datetime format is implicitly done by loopback

```
    "createdon": {
  "type": "Date",
  "required": true,
  "mysql": {
    "columnName": "CreatedOn",
    "dataType": "datetime",
    "nullable": "N"
  },
  "_selectable": false
}
```